# Add and remove class to elements in sequence from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For those who had trouble understanding me before I rephrased my question. I have an array of variables that corresponds to the ids of 5 divs. I am trying to make each div change color for a few seconds one by one but the color changes back before the next div changes color (similar to the lights on a traffic light or a game of Simon). I am currently using a for loop to iterate through each array item. I am using jQuery's .addClass() and removeClass() with setTimeout to try to achieve this effect. Here is my code:

```
//CSS
.color{background-color: red;}
//JavaScript
var div1 = document.getElementById('divID');
etc...
var total = [div1, div2, div3, div4, div5];
for(var n=0; n<counter; n++){
$(total[n]).addClass("color");
setTimeout(function(){
$(total[n]).removeClass("color");
}, 3000);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found a solution. I am posting it for those who are having the same problem. I used jQuery `.delay()` and `.queue()` to create the effect of each div receiving the class one at a time with `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`. Thank you to everyone for your help.

```
for(var n=0; n<counter; n++){
flash(n);
}
function flash(num){
var int = num + 1;
$(total[num]).delay(2000 * int).queue(function(){
$(this).addClass("light").delay(1000).queue(function(){
$(this).removeClass("light");
});
$(this).dequeue();
});
}
```

Comment: your code looks like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```js
var color = ['green', 'red', 'yellow'];
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  $('.light').css('background-color', color[i++ % color.length]);
}, 2000);
```

```css
.light { width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="light"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() is asynchronous, so your loop will race through all items in the array, set all your lights red, then 3 seconds later your setTimeout()'s will all fire at almost the same instant, turning the lights off.

You might want something that looks more like Kld's answer. Use setInterval() to call a function at 3 second intervals, and do your addClass() / removeClass() in there. It may be best if removeClass() operates on all your lights, addClass() on the current one only.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it ,if you want make all be red,you can remove the removeall(),hope i can help you.(my English is not good)

```js
//addClass()函数
function addClass(element,value){
 if(!element.className){
  element.className=value;
 }
 else{
  newClassName=element.className+" "+value;
  elem.className=newClassName;
 }
}
var divs=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var j= -1;
function removeall(){
 for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
  divs[i].className="";
 }
 
}
//自动播放函数
 function autoPlay ()
 {
  setInterval(function () {
   removeall();
   j++;
   addClass(divs[j],"red"); 
  },2000); 
 }
autoPlay();
```

```css
div{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border:1px solid black;
 float: left;
}
.red{
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="one"></div>
 <div id="two"></div>
 <div id="three"></div>
 <div id="five"></div>
 <div id="six"></div>
</body>
```